# ID not returned when adding child in one-to-many using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many

I have a classic one-to-many parent-child relationship between two classes.  Upon initial creation, I create one parent, with an ID = 0 and a child with an ID = 0. I then add a reference to the parent in the child and then add the child to the parent's list.  I save using the code below and both the parent and child are saved in the database with a new ID and the resulting parent and child bean each have and ID specified in the bean.

when i add an additional child bean to **an existing, detached bean**, i create the new child bean, set the ID = 0, and the parent as a reference, then add it to the parent's list.  I then run the edit code listed below and the database shows that the new child has been saved to the database with a new ID, but the new child bean does not show the new ID...

What should i be doing differently when adding a new child to this relationship?

parent class:

```
class parent
{

    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    private List<Child> childList;
}
```

child class:

```
class child
{
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn( name = "ID_PARENT", nullable = false )
    private Parent parent;
}
```

save initial code:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.setID( 0 );

Child child = new Child( );
child.setID( 0 );
child.setParent( parent );

List<Child> childList = new List<>();
childList.add( child );
parent.addChildList( childlist );

em.persist( parent );
em.flush();

parent.getID(); // will display ID in db
parent.getChildList(0).getID(); // will have ID from database
```

edit code:

```
addChild( Parent detachedParent )
{

   Child child = new Child( );
   child.setID( 0 );
   child.setParent( detachedParent );

   detachedParent.getChildList().add( child );

   em.merge( detachedParent );
   em.flush();

   parent.getID(); // will display ID in db
   parent.getChildList( 0 ).getID(); // will have ID from database
   parent.getChildList( 1 ).getID(); // will be 0, but database has new ID
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `em.persist()` it modifies the object you are passing as parameter, but when you use `em.merge()` it loads a fresh copy from the DB and merges the changes from the object you are passing as parameter and then returns that merged object. In your case you inspect the object you passed to `em.merge()` which is not modified by the call, you have to assign the return value of merge to a variable and then from that parent access the child that was added.

```
addChild( Parent detachedParent )
{
   Child child = new Child( );
   child.setID( 0 );
   child.setParent( detachedParent );

   detachedParent.getChildList().add( child );

   parent = em.merge( detachedParent ); // assign merged copy to parent
   em.flush();

   parent.getID(); // will display ID in db
   parent.getChildList( 0 ).getID(); // will have ID from database
   parent.getChildList( 1 ).getID(); // should display same id as the one from DB
}
```